# Get the application start up path

Tags: java, swing, jar, setup-project

How to get path where the set up is being installed of Swing application?

I want to access the application start up path. How is this possible  in Java Swing?

Comment: First define what you mean by 'application startup path'.

Comment: *"I want to access the application start up path."*  Why?  What application feature are you hoping to offer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to know the directory from which your application was started, then

```
String startDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

will do the trick.

Comment: This is not reliable for a non-JWS app., and would fail reliably with a JWS app.

Comment: I can see how this would fail for JWS, but in my experience it works fine for non-JWS stuff. Any pointers where to get more info on this "not reliable" bit?

Comment: 1) Where the code is started from a BAT file in a separate directory.. 2) I guess (but have not checked) when started from a menu item or desktop shortcut created by an installer..  -- In general though, I have yet to find a good use for the `user.dir` information.  On a wider note though this question is usually inspired by a 'wrong need', which is why I am trying to find out what the feature is.

Comment: IC what you mean. Yes. If you want to use this to find where you app (or its JARs) is, then you are right. This is not going to work. And yes, that is usually why people ask for this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson A good use case might be to initialize the directory which is shown the first time you open a `JFileChooser`

Comment: @Robin  I disagree that loose files should be in the application directory.  By extension of that philosophy, there is no reason to ever let the user know the location, let alone open a file chooser pointing to it.  So no, I don't feel that is an example of *good* use.  It would be very handy if the OP could explain the **actual** perceived need.

Comment: Sir suppose my appication is being installed in c:/program files/foldername then i want to know how to get this path from the programming  suppose it is installed in d:/new folder/ then the program should return the path as d:/new folder so that i could get the resources.

Comment: This is generally not possible with Java (or any other language I know about). Think about why you want that, think about if that is good idea, and add that to your question so we can make suggestions of how solve your real problem.